# Change detection not working when web audio involved

Tags: angular, rxjs, web-audio-api

Similar to [Angular change detection with HTMLAudioElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030943/angular-change-detection-with-htmlaudioelement) but its solution doesn't work for me.

In my angular application I want to play short wav files using web audio. While playing the play button shall become a stop button and after finishing the stop button shall become the play button again.
I made a simple audio service that fires an observable right after `AudioBufferSourceNode.start(0)` and also fires the observable in `AudioBufferSourceNode.onended`. I can see in the console that the event fires, but the UI doesn't change. I made a stackblitz demonstrating my problem https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x5ytjt - when actually using the audio api (checkbox set) the UI isn't updated, when only firing the observable (checkbox unset) the UI gets updated.

How can I achieve updating my UI in this case?

component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="playReal">Real playback (vs. fake-events)<br>
  Currently {{playing?"playing":"stopped"}}
  <button type="button" *ngIf="!playing" (click)="play()">play</button>
  <button type="button" *ngIf="playing" (click)="stop()">stop</button>

  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  playing: boolean = false;
  subscription: Subscription;

  playReal: boolean = true;

  constructor(public audio: AudioService, public dataSvc: DataService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.audio.playing$.subscribe(value => {
      this.playing = value;
      console.debug('observer has fired. new value: ', value);
      // solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030943/angular-change-detection-with-htmlaudioelement
      this.ref.markForCheck();
    });

  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }


  play() {
    this.dataSvc.getAudio().subscribe(
      data => {
        if (this.playReal) {
          // do real playback
          this.audio.playBlob(data);
        } else {
          // only fake playing (tell the audio service to emit the event)
          this.audio.hackSetPlaying(true);
        }
      }
    )
  }

  stop() {
    if (this.playReal) {
      this.audio.stopPlay();
    } else {
      this.audio.hackSetPlaying(false);
    }
  }

}
```

audio service:

```
public playBlob( data: Blob ) {
        // playBlob and play inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151121/how-to-play-wav-audio-byte-array-via-javascript-html5

        // create audio context if necessary
        if (!this.audioCtx) {
            this.audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        }

        // use file reader to convert blob to ArrayBuffer
        let fr: FileReader = new FileReader();

        fr.onload = () => {
            // after loading decode and play the wav file
            this.audioCtx.decodeAudioData(<ArrayBuffer>fr.result, (res) => {this.play(res);});
        }

        fr.readAsArrayBuffer(data);
    }

    private play(audioBuff: AudioBuffer) {
        if (!this.audioSrc) {
            this.audioSrc = this.audioCtx.createBufferSource();
        }
        this.audioSrc.buffer = audioBuff;
        this.audioSrc.connect(this.audioCtx.destination);
        this.audioSrc.start(0);
        this.playing = true;
        this.playingSubject.next(this.playing);
        console.debug('audioService has set playing to true');
        this.audioSrc.onended = () => {
            this.playing = false;
            this.playingSubject.next(this.playing);
            console.debug('audioService set playing to false');
            this.audioSrc = null; // audioSrc can only be used once
        }
    }
```

Edit: I just learned, that what I'm using aparently is called web audio api and not html5 audio. Corrected tags, title etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46866433/2131459

I have to call `ChangeDetectorRef`'s method `detectChanges()` instead of `markForCheck()`. I've updated the stackblitz.